# Global static function still working in another file

Tags: c, static, global-variables

I declared a global static function in one file

a.c

```
static void Func1(void);
void Func2(void);

void Func1(void) {
    puts("Func1 Called");
}

void Func2(void) {
    puts("Func2 Called");
}
```

and accessed it in b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.c"
void main() {
    Func1();
    Func2();
}
```

the program complied successfully, but as per provided information this should give error: `undefined reference to Func1`. What wrong is happening here?

Comment: When you included `a.c`, the static function was defined in the current translation unit or TU. The functions become visible to the code in the TU.  This is why you include headers, not source code, usually.

Comment: `#include "a.c"`...that's not how your use the source files. You compile and link them together, you don't include them in other source files!!

Comment: do NOT `#include` c source files.  Rather compile them separately and then link them together .  Write a header file that has the prototypes and extern statements for any thing needed across files and include that header file in every file that needs those cross file references, including the file that contains the actual references

Answer (score 2):

You don't include a source file in another, you compile and link them together.

In you case, by saying `#include "a.c"`, you're essentially putting the whole content of `a.c` into `b.c` and then starting the compilation, so the `static` functions and their calls are present in the same translation unit. Thus, there is no issue for compiler to find the called function.

Instead, if you do something like

```
gcc a.c b.c -o a.out //try to compile and link together
```

you'll see the expected error, as in this case, `a.c` and `b.c` will be two separate translation units.

Answer (score 0):

You declare in `header` files and define in `.c` files. So you must use header files to represent the variables or functions you defined. Instead if you use `.c` files then it leads to multiple definitions.I think that is why you can access that global function.